# Understanding TypeScript <T extends any[]>

Tags: typescript, types

#### `getLength`, it *seems* to work

These two functions read to me as basically the same (The second is perhaps more generic as it will accept objects with properties beyond those found on just arrays):

At runtime, they **are** the same javascript.

```ts
function getLength<T>(
  // v is an array of some type T
  // This could be the type 'any',
  // so I know nothing about what's inside
  v: T[] 
): number {
  return v.length;
}
```

```ts
function getLength2<T extends any[]>(
  // v is an array, I know nothing 
  // about what's inside
  v: T
): number {
  return v.length;
}
```

#### `flattenArray`... ah, okay, it doesn't *really* work

If I do the same substitution here, however, I start to see type errors.

```ts
function flattenArray<T>(
  a:T[][]
) : T[] {
  return a.reduce((prev:T[], curr:T[]) => [...prev,...curr], [] as T[]);
}
```

```ts
function flattenArray<T extends any[]>(
  a:T[]
) : T {
  return a.reduce((prev:T, curr:T) => [...prev,...curr], [] as T);
}
```

Errors:

1. `Type 'T[number][]' is not assignable to type 'T'`
2. `Conversion of type 'never[]' to type 'T' may be a mistake`

As far as I can see, I can type-cast the flattened result array and I can circumvent the type system entirely to create the empty array.

```ts
function flattenArray<T extends any[]>(
  a:T[]
) : T {
  return a.reduce((prev:T, curr:T) => [...prev,...curr] as T, [] as unknown as T);
}
```

This seems like a red flag to me. I suspect there's something I'm not understanding about how the type system works. When I say `T extends any[]`, I'm thinking of T as having at least all the properties of an Array. It may have more, but not less. So I can use T as though it were an Array.

Any insight would be helpful!

Comment: On mobile now, but the problem is using an array as of it were `T`, if `T` has more properties then `reduce` is not going to output something with those properties. It’s the output of the function and not the input that’s the problem.

Comment: You've got some unrelated errors in there; could you clear them up to make this a [mre]?  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WoJxam) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it or worry about distractions like other errors.

Comment: @jcalz Ah, alright. Of course. That makes sense to me (if you put it as an answer I'll accept it). Also, I don't get any errors in my IDE for any save one of the examples (then only the related errors listed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, `T extends any[]` means that `T` must be assignable to an array type, but it is allowed to have extra properties (as required by [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system)).  This is not a problem for the *input* to the function, but cannot be guaranteed by the *output*.  As an example:

```
function flattenArrayBad<T extends any[]>(a: T[]): T {
  return a.reduce<T>((prev, curr) => [...prev, ...curr], []);
  // ------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Type 'T[number][]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  // T[number][]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', 
  // but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any[]'
}
```

Here I've manually specified the type parameter in the [call signature of `Array.prototype.reduce`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/90600e1b17edb9072557816657254001a07c3ca0/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1386) to be `T`, so that the compiler knows to treat both the empty array initial value `[]` and the callback `prev` and return type as `T`.  But, as you saw, it complains that `T[number][]` is not assignable to `T`.  What does this mean?

Well, the compiler knows that `[...prev, ...cur]` is going to be a new array whose elements are the same as the array elements of `T`.  The array elements of `T` are what you get when you index into an array of type `T` with a numeric index of type `number`.  So `T[number]` is that element type.  If you make an array of that, it's an `Array<T[number]>`, a.k.a. `T[number][]`.

And the compiler is telling you that it cannot guarantee that `[...prev, ...cur]` of type `T[number][]` will be of type `T` as well.  Especially in the case where `T` has extra properties, those properties of `cur` will not be copied into the new array, so `[...prev, ...cur]` will not have these properties.  As we can verify:

```
const arr1 = Object.assign([1, 2, 3], { a: 1 });
const arr2 = Object.assign([4, 5, 6], { a: 2 });
const flattenedBad = flattenArrayBad([arr1, arr2]);
/* const flattenedBad: number[] & {
    a: number;
} */
try {
  console.log(flattenedBad.a.toFixed(2)); // no compiler error, but
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // RUNTIME ! flattenedBad.a is undefined
}
```

Here `flattenedBad` is produced by a call to `flattenArrayBad` which claims to return a value of type `T`. In this case `T` is of type `number[] & {a: number}`, since both `arr1` and `arr2` have an extra `a` property of type `number`.  The return type annotation of `flattenArrayBad` is `T`, so `flattenedBad` is therefore also supposed to be of type `number[] & {a: number}`.  That means the compiler lets us index into it with the key `a` and try to call a `number` method like `toFixed()` on it.  And kaboom, we have a runtime error because the actual value returned by `flattenArrayBad` does not have the extra property.

And that's what the error is telling you; yes, `T[number][]` is a subtype of `any[]`, but it might not be a subtype of `T`, because someone can specify `T` to be something different from `T[number][]`.

---

The fix here, if you want to keep `T extends any[]` (instead of making the function generic in the array element type instead of the array type itself), is to just let `flattenArray()` return a value of type `T[number][]`, the type the compiler already sees `reduce()` as returning:

```
function flattenArrayGood<T extends any[]>(a: T[]) {
  return a.reduce<T[number][]>((prev, curr) => [...prev, ...curr], []);
}

const flattenedGood = flattenArrayGood([arr1, arr2]);
// const flattenedGood: number[]

flattenedGood.a // <-- compiler error, Property 'a' does not exist on type 'number[]'
```

Now `flattenedGood` is seen to be of type `number[]` and is not erroneously thought to have a property of type `a`.  If you try to index into it with `a`, the compiler gets angry with you.  So you can't call `flattenedGood.a.toFixed(2)` without getting a helpful compiler error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-EfmgvaIFQsQDkOI5jvgE7WAACuZhT4GMuKNBQcBYC0bT0AwzTnEgKITJmanFEAA)