# Generic array spread and assignment types

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand better how TypeScript treats types for arrays, specifically generics during spread. One initial question for me was this example:

```
const spread = <T extends unknown[]>(arr: T): T => [...arr]; //T[number][]' is not assignable to type 'T'
```

Initially I'd like to understand what is preventing `T[number][]` from being reduced to `T`. I more or less understand that the type `unknown[]` is probably too loose in some way because I can do things I would consider unexpected such as:

```
const test = <T extends unknown[]>(arr:T):T[number]=>arr[0] //no error
const test2 = <T extends unknown[]>(arr:T):T[number]=>[...arr] //no error
```

Type `T[number]` can accept many things, what is it specifically in the type constraint that is lacking and is there some way to improve it for a scenario where I would like to say this is just an array of anything?

Trying these two options works but for object assign I don't understand why and for the tuple I don't know if it's the most helpful.

```
const tupleSpread = <T extends readonly [unknown,...unknown[]]>(arr: T): T => [...arr]; //no error

const spreadAssign = <T extends unknown[]>(arr: T): T => Object.assign(arr); //no error
```

The above is the main concern of my question. Below I will put a little bit of context which is a minimal but representative version of what I was trying to do which led me to the question about array spread. Here is the groudwork:

```
//two possible kinds of value with key for use as discriminant
type DataMap = {
  string: string;
  number: number;
};

//arrays for these value types mapped over these value types
type ArrayMap = { [K in keyof DataMap]: DataMap[K][] };

//function to apply one payload of type DataMap[T] to one array of type DataMap[K][]
const apply = <T extends keyof DataMap>(
  target: ArrayMap[T],
  payload: DataMap[T]
): ArrayMap[T] => {

  const next = [...target, payload]; //(DataMap[T] | ArrayMap[T][number])[]
  return next //not assignable
};
```

The `apply` function fails type wise, I think in way similar to the simple spread example, just the types are a bit more complex. But essentially I think `ArrayMap[T][number]` does not reduce to `DataMap[T]` just like `T[number][]` did not reduce to `T` in the first example with spread.

I tried shifting the generics a bit to see if I could go around the problem like this:

```
const applyByValueType = <T extends DataMap[keyof DataMap]>(
  target:  T[],
  payload: T
): T[] => {
  return [...target, payload];
};
```

But I think again this just pushed the problem down the line. If I try to use this altered function in context, a similar error comes up again:

```
const unitArrays:ArrayMap={
  number:[],
  string:[]
}

const applyAny = <T extends keyof DataMap> (discriminant:T,unit:DataMap[T])=>{
  const target = unitArrays[discriminant];
  const next = applyByValueType(target, unit)

  unitArrays[discriminant] = next; //not assignable
}
```

Trying to understand a bit better I created a type which would be a tuple that accepts the original array and its matching payload, called acceptable tuple.

```
type AcceptableTuple = { [K in keyof DataMap]:  [ DataMap[K][], DataMap[K]] };
```

And trying to use it, I can see that the members of the tuple are individually assignable but once I put them together, the new tuple is not. Additionally Object assign seems to work here too

```
const applyAnyAcceptable = <T extends keyof DataMap> (discriminant:T,unit:DataMap[T])=>{
  const target = unitArrays[discriminant];

  const isTargetAcceptable:AcceptableTuple[T][0]=target; //yes
  const isUnitAcceptable:AcceptableTuple[T][1]=unit; //yes


  const areBothAcceptable:[AcceptableTuple[T][0],AcceptableTuple[T][0]]=[target,unit] //no
  const areBothAccetpable2:AcceptableTuple[T] = [target,unit] as const //no
    const areBothAccetpableObject:AcceptableTuple[T] = Object.assign([target,unit]) //works with object assign
  
}
```

Here is the link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=72&ssc=1&pln=59&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAOAnApgQwCYwLwwDwBUZkAPKZMdCGAVzAGswQB3MAbQF0A%20AClUUQBcMfAEohhLJxisAdHL6J2AbhgB6VflZhqAWwBGyRRwDkMAJZVGsVBAhmA5mFR6ANshhQQHgJ7x3x-GMAKCDQSFgyaGw8QhIyCipaBmY2Ll5%20AVFMrV0DRUkFVgAGdjVVRiJ%20EERQ8CjIqAAmaIIiUnJKGnpGFg4eBUyxTW19Q3ZJWXl%20UvUKw0RqkLCojHR8EABBfmacVriOxO6UvvTBLOHcsckAeT0AK2RgKBkbO0dTkSW62AQUDA3bA4wC1Yu0El1kr00gNhGJhNgpLcHk8XoD3goRCp1BdRkZ2KYLDArDBXkDnG4PF4oL5-IEvpAQG4ZC4QPZuL80OgAW8wNxWABGAA0jUFAGZ2CJPkF1FAmF54CBAa53HQzOCQAAzGAAN1QLmo7iYZigAAsYHRkN4YBrqjQIO4bDB0BZgIgzDo1agwFAgtS-DAACKoKCoACyqHg0QA3kEYHAoG6wPYhNBE-YlLGiZdBFncRmAL4Z6WqBSobxUG2IDwm5D2nV6g0%20PxUHQRvyYEDawzV2vuXX69x%202u%20mkwLaIMvhyM4KPSADS5mBFu8msDwbDEfYQiDIanrDn7A4MELIXUGtoTzM4EpJPg8BcVvA7ngZZZGBgq6Ha93EdY%20FKngfmADr8GWH5al%20O4bvA%206HuwtThLe95WrsoLxJ0y6rlBU48JmIaIPYyBQEI46Tr%20-6CpmL7eG%206Dbuue7-kEcKkd4jGlJIMAxpmyywMBpDRJMMj4YRUCCjA1G0coZTcNh5GlAAPmOoFsfJOS4hKHCZigUDUIgwL8T6J6nqopqEqA1AuJgcqIHQCErHeD4AELeAAag2yD4KOqFtOhVByTBmFagFaR4XwolCMIHCUXGkkgBg4jMeIR6cTGcY6XpwJCSJRHiXFGDKEExnqHo1ARDWYD2bAtDGqxEACKxU5YGluZ5AI0WZqmarJlp%20b0g5yEbGAKExL5BzmpaWEMRGUjcM6ECuu6nrepkgo1cRAV-hKkgtbxHjhUR0TrXVrDzYtHpON6hVxnthnRG2zluR5Xl%20NwOViV0xpSnGx0qRAp0um6F1elAHFEnERbpURmXg6QGZxkVIQhF%20GzAMAyDwCGyr4NQ97uDO86LhNK7BdN8BbnGrDftBsHRdTe4HqUxl7Q93hDWzaMY1jFI%20fs4JBfTM0wHNgNLZdxH4GtYDGgIm3-iIO08d8%200EYdOC-RO5YAwtQPLaDkMwHtFj4AdUCo%20jmPksgDWc5b2O424W3FOM73w4bysWAAqtLZu29z1vm1zVs43jTv8uM61FkriF8MgTkgKagd2247VJ-7IeO-%20zuCmnwcO8gTslOMrDvVLxqlNHKwoPHiec1AL7Ko0NsW%20n%20dbYJpfraUjq8ZmN3K7HNcmoH9dW0ijzEbn9uh-%200TjyipLvCXptl6DIhlDZdBUEapofvcE8kmilUI31QA) with these types.

Comment: `const spread = <T extends any>(arr: T[]): T[] => [...arr]` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Short answer to what you're trying to do with your `apply` function

Typescript does not infer the relationship between `ArrayMap[T]` and `DataMap[T]` to the extent that it can know that `DataMap[T]` is always assignable to `ArrayMap[T][number]`.

`T extends keyof DataMap` can be `"string" | "number"`, and `DataMap[T]` is thus `string | number`.

`string | number` is not in fact assignable to *any* element in `ArrayMap[T]`, because `ArrayMap["string"]` can only hold strings, and `ArrayMap["number"]` can only hold numbers.

Fortunately there is a very easy and pragmatic approach to deal with this – just assert that your concatenated value is of the correct type and be done with it:

```js
//function to apply one payload of type DataMap[T] to one array of type DataMap[K][]
const apply = <T extends keyof DataMap>(
  target: ArrayMap[T],
  payload: DataMap[T]
): ArrayMap[T] => {
  return [...target, payload] as ArrayMap[T];
};
```

---

##### Longer answer to the question you asked initially, which isn't really the same problem at all :-)

This seems to touch on aspects of [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70131684/21146235) of which the main takeaway is that:

> [`T extends unknown[]`] ... means that `T` must be assignable to an array type, but it is allowed to have extra properties (as required by structural typing). This is not a problem for the input to the function, but cannot be guaranteed by the output.

As a specific example – consider spreading an array that has some extra property:

```js
const val = Object.assign([1,2,3], { foo: "bar" });
// typeof val is (number[] & { foo: string })

const spreadVal = [...val];
// typeof spreadVal is (number[])
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkE4LN)

So, your initial `spread` is not fulfilling its contract – the spread operator may discard properties, so `[...val]` doesn't have the advertised return type `T`.

There are a few ways you can go, depending on what you want to do.

You could change your type parameter to be the type of the array element, rather than the type of the entire array:

```js
const spread = <T>(arr: T[]): T[] => [...arr];
```

TS infers `T` based on all the input elements, widening them as appropriate – so `spread([1,2,3])` would return a `number[]`, but `spread([1,2,"abc"])` would return `(string|number)[]`.

If you wanted to keep `T` as the type of the input array itself, you could achieve that same result kinda cutely using TS's tuple spreading to define the return type:

```js
const spread = <T extends unknown[]>(arr: T): [...T] => [...arr];
```

If you're hoping to maintain a little more precision about the input type and you're using TS5 you could use a slightly cumbersome [const type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters):

```js
const spread = function<const T extends readonly unknown[]>(arr: T)
  : readonly [...T] { return [...arr]; }
```

This will keep the return type somewhat more narrow than the above approaches, so `spread([1,2,"abc"])` would return type `[1,2,"abc"]`.

Also worth mentioning is that you can make your original declaration work by using the object spread operator rather than the array spread operator:

```js
const spread = <T extends unknown[]>(arr: T): T => ({...arr});
```

It looks a little odd but since you're treating the input array as an object, all of its properties are copied across – not just the numerically indexed entries and `.length`.

[Playground for these examples](https://tsplay.dev/N5AZ2N)

Referring back to your original examples, we see why some of your attempts work:

```
// SUCCEEDS because T[number] only includes the numerically-indexed
// properties copied across by the spread operator
const test2 = <T extends unknown[]>(arr:T):T[number]=>[...arr]

// SUCCEEDS because Object.assign copies all properties across from
// the input - same as ({ ...arr })
const spreadAssign = <T extends unknown[]>(arr: T): T => Object.assign(arr);
```