# T extends any[] vs T[]

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have two almost equal  Decorator-like functions:

```
function wrapperModifierExtends <T extends any[], R> (func: (...args: T) => R) {
  return function(...args: T) {
    let result = func(...args)
    console.log("we modified it somehow")
    return result
  }
}
```

and

```
function wrapperModifierArr <T , R> (func: (...args: T[]) => R) {
  return function(...args: T[]) {
    let result = func(...args)
    console.log("we modified it somehow")
    return result
  }
}
```

The only difference is that the first function's type parameter `T` constrained to be an array of any type vs `T[]`.

Then , I have a test function to be modified like this (I intentionally made it a little bit weird) :

```
function sumUp(a: number, b: string) {
  return a+b
}
```

But second function throws a compiler error when trying to apply:

```
//function wrapperModifierExtends<[a: number, b: string], string>
//(func: (a: number, b: string) => string): (a: number, b: string) => string
//Works fine
const newFuncExtends = wrapperModifierExtends(sumUp)


//function wrapperModifierArr<string | number, string>
//(func: (...args: (string | number)[]) => string): (...args: (string | number)[]) => string
//ERROR
const newFuncArr = wrapperModifierArr(sumUp) 

// Argument of type '(a: number, b: string) => string' 
// is not assignable to parameter of type 
//'(...args: (string | number)[]) => //string'.
```

Link to playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-NK4ym6FYluQAB8pbbZZbNRydaoNAlfIps3mDQRDJctpbDMsvKdltX8zL0PXRM7Le70tEIN6-dAMzFk3zRoKM9GCbHEUA)

In first case Typescript successfully infers `[a: number, b: string]` as function parameter (BTW, never saw it before) , but in second case it's just `string | number`.
Even more interesting is that it works for both functions if my to-be-modified function was like this (two numbers):

```
function sumUp(a: number, b: number) {
  return a+b
}
```

My question is, why is this behavior so different, and is there perhaps a better syntax/typing to accomplish such tasks?

Comment: There is a similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70128581/understanding-typescript-t-extends-any) , but I didn't really get it there =(

Comment: When you write `T extends any[]` you are saying that `T` is a type which descends from `any[]`. This allows the compiler to infer a very specific type based on the argument list, `args`. When you say `args` is a `T[]` you've ruled out a tuple type because you've said it's just an array that can hold all the elements of `args`. The difference is between a generic type that's a subtype of array and an array of a generic type.

Comment: `Argument of type '(a: number, b: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: (string | number)[]) => string'`. wrapperModifierArr expects a function like `(a: string|number, b: string|number) => string` where all arguments have to be `string|number` not, some `string` some `number`. That's why `sumUp` is not compatible with `(...args: (string | number)[]) => string`